# When inserting "Runtime:addEventListener("location".... " app to immediately crash - Corona/Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using Corona sdk to write an application, and i need to retrieve the device (androids) location. Using the Corona Simulator this code works:

Runtime:addEventListener( "location", function(e)
    lon = e.longitude
    lat = e.latitude
    print(lat, lon)
    end)

But when I run it on an actual device it crashes instantly, i have tried looking at the log out put:

[image: Log]

But I don't see anything that makes sense to myself.

Comment: Does your's build.settings file contain required data? https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/location/index.html

Comment: Yes it does! as well as others.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code around where you're setting up this listener. Are you doing it from a button by any chance? Also more log messages would be helpful to.  If you upgrade to the latest daily build there will be a new console window that will easily let you copy/paste messages as well as flag the errors in red and yellow.

Comment: BTW: You should not add event listeners that way. Event listeners, if you intend to remove them need an address to a function. You cannot use anonymous functions for this. Please move the function to a named function and pass the name to the addEventListener.